# knockout.js - data-bind value with default

Tags: data-binding, knockout.js

In knockout.js I have a data-bind as follows

```
<input id="lbl" type="text" data-bind="value: $data.quantity" />
```

here I would like to have a condition like if $data.quantity is 0 i need to bind with empty text so can some one help me

Comment: What's `$text`? Did you mean `$data.quantity`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a ternary expression:

```
<input id="lbl" type="text" data-bind="value: quantity() ? quantity() : ''" />
```

The above assumes that your `quantity` property is an observable, if it's not:

```
<input id="lbl" type="text" data-bind="value: quantity ? quantity : ''" />
```

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jqbtj2p3/1/)

Comment: in-line code in view is always better to avoid it . it will be much cleaner and maintainable if we can use a computed here . cheers .

Comment: That's a matter of personal style in this case, the condition is very short and clear and doesn't involve other model data, `computed` would be an over-kill for this.

Comment: So can I wirte like this `<input id="lbl" type="text" data-bind="value: $data.quantity?$data.quantity:""" />`

Comment: Almost. **1.** Why the `$data` at all? **2.** You can't use `"` inside the attribute value of `data-bind` because it is already wrapped with `"`, replace with `'` instead: `value: $data.quantity?$data.quantity:''`.

Comment: I am binding the data from database call so `$data` `value:data-bind="value: $data.quantity?$data.quantity:''` this didn't worked

Comment: Is `quantity` an observable?

Comment: No I will make an ajax call to get data and bind

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71018/discussion-between-dotnet-and-haim770).